# Restart Apache from php error " Found 1 leftover httpd processes "

Tags: php, apache, exec, shell-exec

I want to **restart apache** from php.
I use this code

```
<?php
$output=shell_exec('/etc/init.d/httpd restart &');
echo $output;
exit;
?>
```

The output is this error

> Stopping httpd: [FAILED] Found 1 leftover httpd processes. Killing.
>   Starting httpd:

Does anyone know what's the problem?